# Allow only Logged in user to download images

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an Application based on Monorails which generates images / charts at runtime. The code writes the images to OutputStreams and not to the Appserver hard drive. It allows the user to download the image. I want to make sure that only the logged in user is able to download the image and no one else.

For e.g if any user A tries to download image generated for user B user A should not be able to do that no matter what.

Note: I am not storing the file to the hard disk.

How can I implement this???

Below is the sample code I have written for the image download.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/image";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + imagefilename);
var array = stream.To Array();
Response. OutputStream.Write(array,0,array.length);
Response.End();
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Nothing so far. Still researching, I am more of a Business Layer dev not worked more on the UI side. Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need logic in the code to check if the user logged in 'owns' the image they are trying to download.

If they don't 'own' it, Response.End their request